# Is it possible to make a PC come out of sleep mode remotely?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, sleep, teamviewer

I have recently built a new PC at home and put Team viewer onto it so I could connect in remotely to install software whilst I was at work.

The problem I'm having is, I forgot to turn off Auto Sleep mode and have not set up Wake-On-Lan.

Is it possible to make my new PC leave sleep mode or is it not possible without Wake-On-Lan?

Also, I still have my old PC turned on at home and I am connected to that with Teamviewer if that can be of any help.

Comment: Not possible without WOL.

Comment: If you have a trained bird at home that can jump around on the keyboard....

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing requires Wake-On-LAN. When the machine is in sleep mode, WOL is one of the few subsystems left active that can wake the machine back up.

Other common wake-up methods are USB, such as a key press or mouse click, certain modems, or the RTC (wake up at a certain time) provided by the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a lame joke, but it can actually work. Sometimes...

As others already stated you really need WOL, but it may just be possible to use the other computer to move the mouse attached to the asleep computer and thereby waking it up.

If they are close to each other *on the same table*, try playing something VERY loud, with heavy bass (AC/DC Thunderstruck or something like that), through the speakers of the old computer. That just may create enough vibration in the table to shake the mouse.